# Rails order search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with ordering search results on rails.
I want to order the posts after I searched or filtered but what I'm doing doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code.

posts_controller.rb

```
display
  @posts = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", current_user.following_ids)
  @posts = @posts.find(Like.group(:post_id).pluck(:post_id)).order(params[:change]) if params[:change].present?
end
```

I have a posts_controller which displays the posts user are following to, it works fine. However, when I added an extra code trying to order the posts by the number of likes, error occurs. 
It seems that the second line in post controller extracts all the posts with like instead of only the posts the user are following. If I replace @posts.find with Post.find, all the posts result will be shown and ordered by the number of likes.

by the way, this, @posts.order(created_at: :desc), works fine. It orders only the posts user are following.

like.rb

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, foreign_key: "post_id"
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :post_id, scope: :user_id
end
```

like_controller.rb

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

def create
  @like = current_user.likes.create(post_id: params[:post_id])
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end

def destroy
  @like = Like.find_by(post_id: params[:post_id], user_id: current_user.id)
  @like.destroy
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end

end
```

I'm very new at programming so please forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question. Thank you all very much.

The error message is below:

[image]

Comment: *...when I added an extra code trying to order the posts by the number of likes, error occurs*. It would be helpful if you said what the error is and what line of your code Rails is telling you it is on. But one thing that jumps out at me is this line: `@posts = @posts.find(Like.group(:post_id).pluck(:post_id)).order(params[:change]) if params[:change].present?`. If `params[:change].present?` is false, what do you suppose will be assigned to `@posts` as a value? Even before you call `@posts.find...` you might want to log the value of `@posts` to see if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
When I changed to @posts = Post.find(Like.group(:post_id).order(params[:change]).pluck(:post_id)),
it returns all the posts I have and ordered it properly by the number of likes. So I really don't know how to do it...

Comment: As I mentioned in my prior comment: (1) show the exact error message you got that you mentioned and indicate which line of code the error is talking about (the error message will have it there), and (2) in the error case, examine what the value of `@posts` is before you call `@posts.find...`. You can do that by logging the value of your could try simply `puts @posts.inspect` before your `@posts.find...` call and you should see it on your screen when you run the code. This will determine if `@posts = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", current_user.following_ids)` is doing what you hope.

Comment: A better way to write `@posts = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", current_user.following_ids)` might be: `@posts = Post.where({ user_id: current_user.following_ids })`.

Comment: This is the result.:)
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 23, title: "123", body: "", user_id: 6, created_at: "2020-04-21 09:06:28", updated_at: "2020-04-21 09:06:28", likes_count: 0>, #<Post id: 24, title: "333", body: "", user_id: 6, created_at: "2020-04-21 09:06:40", updated_at: "2020-04-21 09:06:40", likes_count: 0>, #<Post id: 25, title: "Hello World", body: "", user_id: 6, created_at: "2020-04-25 12:28:17", updated_at: "2020-04-25 12:28:17", likes_count: 0>]>

Comment: That's the answer to #2? And what was the exact error message you got from the code you show in your question (answer to #1)?

Comment: I added an image showing the error message. It says it found 2 results and that's fine. But I don't know why it was looking for 7. I only want to show that 2 results

Comment: It looks more like a warning than an error. Since it provides reasonable results, you can probably safely ignore it.

Comment: Oh I think I misled you. The values of posts I provided are 
`@posts = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", current_user.following_ids)`
And the error occurs in the next code.
`@posts = posts.find(Like.group(:post_id).pluck(:post_id)).order(params[:change]) if params[:change].present?`
I want to order my posts after showing the posts user are following.:)

Comment: It's a bit confusing because the code you show in your question doesn't match the code you show in the screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry I changed it but it does the same error..

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using 6.0.:)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `find`, when given an array, requires that all of the id's in the array be present or you get an error. In the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find), it states:

> If one or more records can not be found for the requested ids, then `RecordNotFound` will be raised.

I would use a different mechanism to retrieve the records:

```
@posts = @posts.where(id: Like.group(:post_id).pluck(:post_id)).
              order(params[:change]) if params[:change].present?
```

This will locate just those records that satisfy the condition.

This feels a little clunky. There might be a cleaner way of getting this result depending upon what relationship might exist in your models between `Like`, `Post`, and `Group`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error disappears but the posts are not being ordered by the number of likes now..

Comment: @Sohn I only show part of the expression since the rest is the same.  That's what I meant by the `...`. Did you append the `.order(params[:change])` that you have in your original? I added it to my answer to be clear. If you need a different ordering, then a different or additional `.order` expression will be needed.

Comment: I have `.order(params[:change])` in it, and it's just showing the same result as `@posts = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", current_user.following_ids)`. That means it's not ordering..

Comment: @Sohn what's the value of `params[:change]`? Whatever that is, that's what it will order by. If you know you want to order by likes, why not use `.order(:like)` (or whatever the attribute is called)?

Comment: The value is  'count(post_id) desc'.  And I uploaded my like_controller.rb, I use post_id because I added it when created one like..

Comment: @Sohn ok so that is ordering in descending order of number of posts. But you're saying you want to order by number of likes?

Comment: actually the post_id in like model is storing the number of likes and it works when I want to order all of the posts by the number  of like. I don't know why it doesn't work when it comes to only the posts the user are following..